# Using Github as source control for Exercism

Tags: github

I have been told to use my GitHub as my source control for my Exercism account on the practice mode. I don't quite know what it means and my question is how can I do it?

I tried installing the Exercism CLI on my windows but I'm not quite sure if I'm on the right path. I need an explenation on what it means and how can I use it as a source control.